# getting the last opened file

Tags: macos, bash

input file:

```
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
```

input file is the list of opened files (opening file means 1 line of file)  i want to get the last opened file in

e.g. : **get last opened file in dir /Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/**

output:

```
wtf.txt
```

Comment: do you mean `head -1 input_file.txt | cut -d\| -f1` ? Good luck.

Comment: "Last" as last line in the file, or file with newest modification timestamp (access timestamps are usually turned off for obvious performance reasons) or something else?

Comment: @tripleee i mean the last file with given folder (~/inc/face/).14th line-`wtf.txt`..other examples is: for folder ~/inc/twiiter/ output is `wtf.txt` - 15th line, for folder ~/inc/linked/ it's `omg.txt` last line in file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fetches the last line in the file whose second field is the desired folder name, and prints the first field.

```
awk -F '\|' '$2 == "/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/" { f=$1 }
  END { print f }' file
```

To test whether the most recent file is also an existing file, I would use the shell to reverse the order with `tac` and perform the logic; skip the files in the wrong path, and the ones which don't exist, then print the first success and quit.

```
tac file |
while IFS='|' read -r basename path _; do
    case $path in "/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face") ;; *) continue;; esac
    test -e "$path/$basename" || continue
    echo "$basename"
    break
done |
grep .
```

The final `grep .` is to produce an exit code which reflects whether or not the command was successful -- if it printed a file, it's okay; if none of the extracted files existed, return error.

Below is my original answer, based on a plausible but apparently incorrect interpretation of your question.

Here is a quick attempt at finding the file with the newest modification time from the list. I avoid [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), prefering instead to use properly machine-parseable output from [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html). Since your input file is line-oriented, I assume no file names contain newlines, which simplifies things quite a bit.

```
awk -F '\|' '$2 == "/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/" { print $2 $1 }' file |
sort -u |
xargs stat -f '%m %N' |
sort -rn |
awk -F '/' '{ print $NF; exit(0) }'
```

The first `sort` is to remove any duplicates, to avoid running `stat` more times than necessary (premature optimization, perhaps), the `stat` prefixes each line with the file's modification time expressed as seconds since the epoch, which facilitates easy numerical sorting by age, and the final Awk script neatly combines `head -n 1 | rev | cut -d / -f1 | rev` i.e. extract just the basename from the first line of output, then quit.

If there is any way to use a less wacky input format, that would be an improvement (probably of your life in general as well).

The output format from `stat` is not properly standardized, but your question is tagged <del>[linux](/questions/tagged/linux)</del>*[osx](/questions/tagged/osx)* so I assume <del>GNU coreutils</del> *BSD* `stat`.  If portability is desired, maybe look at `find` (which however may be overkill and/or not much better standardized across diverse platforms) or write a small Perl or Python script instead. (Well, Ruby too, I suppose, but personally, I'd go with Perl.)

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '{ $t{$F[0]} = (stat($F[1].$F[0]))[10]
    if !defined $t{$F[0]} and $F[1] == "/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/" }
  END { print ((sort { $t{$a} <=> $t{$b} } keys %t)[-1]) }' file
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, problem is i have mac and i can't use   anything like `stat`. i can use only standard utilities.

Comment: Then why on `<blink>Earth</blink>` is this tagged [tag:linux]?

Comment: Updated for [tag:osx]; for reference, the corresponding Linux `stat` command would be `stat -c '%y %f'`.  But based on your comment above, you apparently don't care about file modification times, so just look at the very beginning of the updated answer. (And please take more care to properly define your problem next time you have a question.)

Comment: `stat` *is* a standard install, it's just that its options are not standardized, so different versions require different command lines to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: it returns `xargs: illegal option -- i`  don't know why

Comment: The `-i` option wasn't really useful here anyway; sorry about that. Answer updated.

Comment: i watched man pages for utilities you're using You may don't understand task. I can't use `stat` because i work only with informations in input file...PS your solution prints out `|`

Comment: OK, thank you, it's easier than i awaited. PS. i have to edit you answer...here is the solution: `awk -F '|' '$2 == "/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/" { f=$1 }
  END { print f }' file`

Comment: Oops, right, I had transcribed your test file incorrectly when testing.  Updated.

Comment: i just realized this: if the file in folder is deleted over time, record of opening stays in Input file. also it will printout the name of last modified files which exists..any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to verify that the file exists, and if not, print an earlier, existing match from the list?

Answer (score 0):

`atime` – The `atime` (access time) is the time when the data of a file was last accessed. Displaying the contents of a file or executing a shell script will update a file’s `atime`, for example. You can view the `atime` with the `ls -lu` command

http://www.techtrunch.com/linux/ctime-mtime-atime-linux-timestamps

So in your case, will do the trick.

`ls -lu /Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/`

Comment: Why would you use `-ctime` instead of `-atime` ?

Comment: This examines all the files in the directory, not just the ones enumerated in the input file.